# get characters from file rather than getchar

Tags: c++

I cannot work out how to read text from a file rather than from getchar()

calc entropy of a string

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
#include<math.h>
#include <string>
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
#include <fstream>
#include <cstring>
using namespace std;

double log2(double number) 
{
return log(number)/std::log(2.);
}

int main() {

unsigned long table[256], total = 0;
double entropy = 0;
char mychar;

string line;
ifstream myfile ("sometext.txt");
if (myfile.is_open())
{
while ( getline (myfile,line) )
{
cout << line << '\n';
}

}
short i;

for(i=0; i<256; i++) 
table[i] = 0;

while(1)  
{  
mychar = getchar();
```

how to read from myfile.txt ?

```
if (mychar==EOF) // ctrl Z 
{break;}
table[mychar]++;
}

for(i=33;i<127;i++)
if(table[i]) {
total += table[i]; 
entropy -= log2(table[i])*table[i];
}

entropy /= total;
entropy += log2(total);

printf("Total Characters: %6d\n",total);
printf("Entropy: %5.6f\n",entropy); 
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The loop reading lines with `std::getline()` reads the content of the file! You could actually process the data from the `std::string`s already read:

```
while (std::getline(myfile, line)) {
    std::cout << line << '\n';

    for (std::string::const_iterator it(line.begin()), end(line.end()); it != end; ++it) {
        unsigned char mychar = *it;
        ++table[mychar];
    }
}
```

The inner loop iterates over all characters in the string `line`. It obtains an `unsigned char` from the character currently processed (i.e., from `*it`) because `char` may be signed type and yield negative values which probably doesn't work too well. The ASCII characters are all positive but, e.g., the u-umlaut `ü` from my name may become a negative values; I'd guess that isn't really an issue for your input but I prefer code which works even when unexpected things happen.

In any case, this loops terminates when the `std::getline()` failed because there is no further data. If you want to read the data *again*, you'll either need to open a new `std::ifstream` or reset the `std::ifstream` you got:

```
myfile.clear();                        // clear error flags
myfile.seekg(0, std::ios_base::beg); // move to the start of the file
```

To actually read individual chars as `int` you could use

```
mychar = myfile.get();
```

Personally, I'd be inclined to read the characters using iterators, though:

```
for (std::istreambuf_iterator<char> it(myfile), end; it != end; ++it) {
    char mychar = *it; // well, you could keep using *it, of course
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Judging from the code in the question, might as well read and print the lines, but take the characters from the lines instead of the file again, and add in the newlines manually. This is definitely all good knowledge to have, though.

Comment: @chris: good point! I updated the answer to mention that the lines could be used immediately.

Comment: Good idea - but exactly how to take the characters from the printed lines?

Comment: @James: Well, the characters are in the `line` string! You could access them, e.g., using `for (std::string::const_iterator it(line.begin()), end(line.end()); it != end; ++it) { char mychar = *it; /*...*/ }` or access the elements of the string different, e.g., using `line[index]` to get the `char` at position `index`.

Comment: Sorry,I am a biochemist and not much a programer. I'm still a bit confused.

Comment: @Dietmar - Thank you. The code works and I can get back to theory :-)

Answer (score 0):

Use fgetc(). You can pass it a FILE pointer.